# Creating a theme from API call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating an app, my end goal is to have an api call which contains all the colours and fonts that i need. Is there a way of creating a new theme or updating the variable.scss file with the results?

Comment: No way to override the .scss file as long at this file does not exist in the final release (the package that contains your app). The .scss files from the project are used to generate some .css (plain css files/sheets). What you can do is retrieve from the server a plain css too and then create 'on the fly' (via javascript) an <style> in the index.html file and insert those css rules in this <style tag.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler s comment should be the answer